# How to move a selected GameObject to a location using the mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help with using raycast to select an object and move it to another location the player left-clicks on. I'm doing well so far, however I can't get the Cylinder that's selected to move. Here's the code I have so far:

```
public class ClicknDrag : MonoBehaviour {

private GameObject selected;
private bool unselected = true;

void Update ()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && hit.transform.tag == "Cylinder" && unselected == true)
    {
        selected = hit.transform.gameObject;
        unselected = false;
    }

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && unselected == false && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        selected.transform.position = hit.transform.position;
        unselected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do that `Physics.Raycast` only once ... it is quite expensive! Also the check for `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` is redundant. And store the result of `Camera.main` which is also quite expensive (afaik under the hood it uses something similar to `GameObjevt.FindWithTag("MainCamera")`)

Also note: `GetMouseButtonDown(0)` returns true only **once** in the frame when the button pressed the first time. Later for moving you probably rather want to use `GetMouseButton(0)` which is `true` **as long as** the button stays pressed.

And finally if you want a smooth movement to the exact hit position instead of the hit objects position you might want to use `hit.point` instead of `hit.transform.position`

The `unselected` flag is kind of redundant: You could directly use `if(selected)` and later reset it to `selected = null`

So something like

```
[SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

private void Awake ()
{
    if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
}

private void Update()
{
    Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Cylinder"))
    {
        // First click -> select object
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !selected)
        {
            selected = hit.transform.gameObject;
        }
        // button stays pressed > move object
        else if (selected && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            selected.transform.position = hit.point;
        }
        // Second click release object
        else if(selected && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            selected = null;
        }
    }
    // ToDo: What if the Raycast doesn't hit? Then you can't release object?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the position of the raycast hit, you need to use hit.point, instead of hit.transform.position. hit.TRANSFORM.position will return the position of the object hit.

Also, in your case, even after selection, you're still raycast-hitting the cylinder, so you could disable the collider of the selected object when it is selected. This way it gets ignored by the raycast, which will hit the next object it finds (e.g. the floor).

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-transform.html